# Removing all duplicated pairs in a Python list

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need a function to remove duplicated pairs from a list. The following is example list:

`a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

I need remove all pairs `[a[i], a[i+1]]` if `a[i] == a[i+1]` until all such pairs eliminated:

`[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

`[1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1]`

`[1, 2, 3, 3, 1]`

`[1, 2, 1] - final list`

I wrote a `removepairs` function:

```
def removepairs(list):
    result_prev = list
    while True:
        result = __removepairs_once__(result_prev)
        if len(result) == len(result_prev):
            return result
        else:
            result_prev = result

def __removepairs_once__(list):
    result = []
    most_recent_element = None
    for i in list:
        if i != most_recent_element:
            if most_recent_element:
                result.append(most_recent_element)
            most_recent_element = i
        else:
            most_recent_element = None
    if most_recent_element:
        result.append(most_recent_element)
    return result
```

Please help me to make it better.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should try re-making `__removepairs_once__` only using results.
No `most_recent_element`.

So, you would want to retry you algorithm, `most_recent_element` can be `results[-1]`.
Using this you should come to this stub code:

```
def _remove_pairs(list_):
    result = []
    for item in list:
        if item == results[-1]:
            # remove last item
            # don't add this item
        else:
            # add this item
    return result
```

Using this you should notice that it'll error if results is empty, this means you should use the else if it is.
The if block is surprisingly simple, it's `results.pop()`. And the else is `results.append(item)`.

```
def _remove_pairs(list_):
    results = []
    for item in list_:
        if results and item == results[-1]:
            results.pop()
        else:
            results.append(item)
    return results
```

A quick test of this actually (unsurprisingly) returns the final list that you wanted.

---

***Don't*** use `__{}__` for anything! Only use it for pythons magic functions!

You should also not use `list` but `list_` as then you can still convert something to a list.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that is a really neat idea.  I would change a couple things, though.

I don't think `removepairs` is a good name because it doesn't actually remove anything from the list; it returns a new list with the pairs removed.  Therefore, I would call it `get_singles`.

You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in type.  If you decide later in your function that you want to convert a tuple to a list, you might use `list(my_tuple)`.  Oh no!  `'list' object is not callable`.  I'm not using a list object; I am using `list`!  Well, no actually.  You can't have two things with the same name.  You should always avoid using a name that shadows a built-in.

You don't need to check the length of `result_prev` for each iteration.  Instead, keep a counter of the current position and check that against the length of `result`.  (That will come in useful below).  That is more efficient because you aren't re-calculating the length each time.

I wouldn't put `__` around `removepairs_once`.  When you do that, you are making the function private.  That means that a wildcard import (`from ... import *`) will not include that function.  I don't see that as a benefit.  That function might be useful for other modules.  I wouldn't bother renaming it, though, because I will present another solution that could just take it out.

My proposed solution creates just one list instead of a bunch of intermediate lists.  It works by starting at index `0` and working up to the end.  If a number is the same as a previous number, both numbers are removed and the index goes down so that we can re-check.  Here it is:

```
def removepairs(numbers):
    i = 0 
    prev = None
    while i < len(numbers):
        number = numbers[i]
        if number == prev:
            numbers.pop(i) # Current
            numbers.pop(i - 1) # Previous
            i -= 1 # We deleted two, so the next is back one
        else:
            i += 1
        if i:
            prev = numbers[i - 1]
        else:
            prev = None

    return numbers
```

Comment: Thank you (+1). Actually, I would like to make `remove_pairs` unavailable outside of module, so I changed it to `__remove_pairs__`. Is it a right way?

Comment: @Loom: If the module is imported by `import module_name`, you can use `module_name.__remove_pairs__` anyway.  It would take a lot to change that.  What you can affect, however, is what happens when the functions are imported by `from module_name import *`.  For best practices, see [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).  It says to define `__all__`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way could be to perform changes on the source list itself.

```
def remove_duplicate(l):
  curr_index = 0
  while curr_index < ( len(l) - 1 ):
    if l[curr_index] == l[curr_index + 1]:
      del l[curr_index:curr_index + 2]
      curr_index = 0
    else:
      curr_index += 1

source = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6]
remove_duplicate(source)
```